# characterization of number fields that occur inside some prime cyclotomic field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

It is the case that every finite normal field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with abelian Galois group is contained in a cyclotomic extension.  What about *prime* cyclotomic extensions?

Is there a simple characterization of those number fields $K$ that occur as subfields of some $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ for $p$ a prime?  Clearly $K$ must be normal over $\mathbb{Q}$ with cyclic Galois group. Do all such occur?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Kronecker-Weber theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes, thanks I should have added that as background. ive edited it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the $p$-adic numbers, their extensions (unramified, totally and tamely ramified) and the binomial series proof that $E/F$ totally ramified of degree $n$ coprime with $p$ implies $E(\zeta_m) =F(\zeta_m,\pi_F^{1/n})$ where $\pi_F$ is an uniformizer of $F$ and $p\nmid m$ ? From there we find that $K/\Bbb{Q}$ abelian implies $K_p/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is abelian and $K_p=\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_l,\zeta_{p^e})$ where $e$ is the ramification index of $p$ in $O_K$. Thus we can read the least $N$ such that $K\subset\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$ directly from its ramified primes and residue fields @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @reuns Thank you that's a bit over my head but it sounds like it will help. can you recommend a place Where I can read about that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ill-posed. By Galois theory, the subfields of the cyclotomic field $L=\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ are the subfields $L^G$ fixed by the subgroups $G$ of $(\mathbf Z/p)^*$. But I guess you ask for more, e.g. for primitive elements of the $L^G$ ? If so, the answer is given by the so called *Gaussian periods* mod $p$ : let $G$ be a subgroup of $(\mathbf Z/p)^*$; for any $a\in \mathbf Z/p$, define $S(G,a)$ as the sum over $g\in G$ of the elements $\zeta_p^{ag}$. After establising some properties of the Galois action on the Gaussian periods, it is easy to show that $L^G=\mathbf Q(S(G,1))=\mathbf Q(S(G,a))$ for all $a\in(\mathbf Z/p)^*$. The same result is valid on replacing $p$ by an integer $n$ which is square-free. The most accessible ref. for a beginner is the bachelor thesis of D. Tijsma, "Gaussian Periods", Utrecht, 2016, which you can find using Google. The result I cited is lemma 5-12 therein. Weaker results are available for non square-free $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for characterization like that of kronecker- weber.  For instance does every normal extension of Q With cyclic Galois group occur?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You ask for "a simple characterization of those number fields K that occur as subfields of some Q(ζp) for p a prime". The theory of Gaussian periods gives explicitly all of them, even more precisely than the K-W. theorem.